# Change of state of gas

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

Why is it necessary to liquify a gas and then kept in container? We know gases take the shape of container they are kept in. So we take a container of our desired amount and then we can collect gas in that container. I that's why don't understand why liquification is done.

Comment: Be specific. What gas? Many gases are kept in gaseous form. Other gases with high enough critical T and low enough critical p are kept liquified, as more of such gas fits the container. Particularly methane/natural gas has Tc 191 K and p_c 46 atm.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. This is for some sort of understanding so I took a general gas. Could you please explain why some gases are kept in gaseous form and others are liquified?I t will be a great help.

Comment: A CO2 cylinder is gas form, a liquid nitrogen tank holds both. As a liquid it takes less volume than an equivalent ammount of the gaseous state, as liquid is drawn off gas fills the removed liquid volume -or- as gas is drawn off gas is released from the liquid form as gas to fill the removed gas volume..

Answer (score 0):

These gases are typically held at temperatures below their critical point, which means that, at sufficiently high pressure, they become liquids, see [Critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)). Thsi is what would happen in the scenario proposed in the OP - no special liquification effort needed.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an equal amount of gas and liquid occupies different volumes at the same pressure and temperature. Therefore it would be convenient to minimize the volume, and the liquid offers the best solution.

Why, then, not all the fluids are stored in liquid form? The answer is related to the different phase diagrams of various fluids. A part other non-physical reasons (like the cost of liquefying), the obvious requirement is that the coexistence between liquid and gas at room temperature does correspond to a pressure sustainable by the container walls.